# Merge different Array variables value into JSON Object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, javascript-objects

I have below respective variables holding the bill# in an array.

```
billA = [12345]  // For "Pizzahut" Billsystem 

billB = [96754,75432]  // For "Subway" Billsystem

billC = [63946]   // For "XYZ" Billsystem
```

I intend to combine the above values into a JSON object like the below format.

Result Output:

```
{"BillDetails" : [{billsystem: "PizzaHut" , billnum: "12345"}, {billsystem : "Subway" , billnum "96754" }, {billsystem : "Subway" , billnum "75432"},{billsystem : "XYZ" , billnum "63946"}]}
```

Comment: How does your system know billA is PizzaHut? Is there an association somewhere?

Comment: No there is not an association.I will be assuming if I extract value from this variable,it will belong to that billsystem. For billA it is Pizzahut , for billB it is Subway ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `flatMap` along with an array of billing systems

```js
let billA = [12345] // For "Pizzahut" Billsystem 
let billB = [96754, 75432] // For "Subway" Billsystem
let billC = [63946] // For "XYZ" Billsystem
let billD = [] // For "Testing" Billsystem
let types = ["Pizzahut", "Subway", "XYZ", "Testing"]
let json = {
  BillDetails: [billA, billB, billC, billD].flatMap((e, i) => (e?.map(b => ({
    billSystem: types[i],
    billNum: b
  }))))
}

console.log(json)
```

Comment: What if before running the script to transform this array we need to do validation check if the variables values are not null.

Comment: you mean the array billC for example being `billC=[null]`?

Comment: Like the array is empty( not holding any values) in variables. billC = []

Comment: I updated the answer. basically you would just use the `?` in front of the array iterator : `... e?.map(b => ({ ... `

Answer (score 1):

```
const obj = {
   "BillDetails" : [
       ...billA.map(item=>({billsystem: "PizzaHut" , billnum: String(item)})),
       ...billB.map(item=>({billsystem: "Subway" , billnum: String(item)})),
       ...billC.map(item=>({billsystem: "XYZ" , billnum: String(item)})),
   ]
}
```

Comment: @James `...billA.map` will not map through copied array. I'm using spread syntax to merge arrays.